# Approximating an arbitrary set by a Borel set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Q) Show that for each (not necessarily measurable) subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, there exists a Borel subset $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A\subset B$ and $\lambda^*(A) = \lambda(B)$ where $\lambda^*$ is the outer measure.

I know that for a Lebesgue measurable $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, there exists a Borel set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $B\supset A$ and $\lambda(B-A)=0$. How can I go from there?

Comment: In simple English you have made a wrong claim -:). If such a set $B$ exists for any set $A$ then every set would be Lebesgue measurable!

Comment: I see, so my statement holds for Lebesgue measurable $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$ there exist open interval $U_k$ with $A \subset \bigcup_k U_k$ and $\lambda (B_n) \leq \lambda^{*} (A)+\frac  1 n$ where $B_n=\bigcup_k U_k$. Take $B=\bigcap B_n$. Then $A \subseteq B$, $B$ is a Borel set and $\lambda (B) \leq \lambda^{*} (A)$. The reverse inequality is obvious.

Comment: May I know why there exists $B_n$ s.t. $\lambda(B_n)\leq \lambda^*(A)+\frac{1}{n}$? Thanks.

Comment: That is from the definition of $\lambda^{*}$. @Garfield